# Why can't I get the id of an element - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and was wondering if someone can help me with, what i believe is an easy solution.

I am trying to get the id of a link when click and then alert the id out like this:

What am I missing here? cause firebug is giving me a 'id is not defined' error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.category").click(function(){
      $.post("index.php", { id: "$(this).attr('id')"},
         function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + id);
      });
     //return false to insure the page doesn't refresh
     return false;
    });

});
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `{ id: "$(this).attr('id')" }`, you are creating an object with the `id` property set to the literal string `"$(this).attr('id')"`.

To post the actual ID of the clicked element, you need to remove the quotes and set the `id` property to the value of the expression, like this: `{ id: $(this).attr('id') }`.

Also, the expression `{ id: $(this).attr('id') }` creates an object with an `id` property.
It does not create any `id` variable, so you can't use the `id` non-variable in the callback.

To fix this, you need to make a variable, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("a.category").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post("index.php", { id: id },
            function(data){
              alert("Data Loaded: " + id);
            }
        );
       //return false to insure the page doesn't refresh
       return false;
    });    
});
```

Comment: Hey Slaks, typo in first line: you mean `id` property.